# How to mount Windows share on boot using mount.cifs and autofs/automount?

Tags: centos, centos5, cifs, automount, autofs

I'm having some trouble mounting a network share using autofs. I have added the following line to */etc/auto.master*:

> ```
> /mnt/mountpoint       /etc/auto.servername
> ```

I then created the file */etc/auto.servername* with the following contents:

> ```
> server-ip -fstype=cifs,rw,noperm,user=DOMAIN\username,pass=password ://server-ip/share
> ```

I then run `service autofs restart` and `ls /mnt/mountpoint` to determine whether autofs succeeds in mounting the share (it does not.) The result from `dmesg` is:

> ```
> CIFS VFS: Send error in SessSetup = -13
> CIFS VFS: cifs_mount failed w/ return code = -13
> Status code returned 0xc000006d NT_STATUS_LOGON_FAILURE
> ```

However, if I simply run `mount -t cifs //server-ip/share /mnt/mountpoint -o user=username` and enter the password on prompt, the share is mounted without any problems. I have verified the correct password is */etc/auto.servername*.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

change

> server-ip -fstype=cifs,rw,noperm,user=DOMAIN\username,pass=password ://server-ip/share

to

> share -fstype=cifs,rw,noperm,user=username,pass=password,domain=domain ://server-ip/share

Comment: That's what's done it for me. mount was not appreciating the domain\user backslash.
Using the domain as another parameter worked just fine

Answer (score 1):

I would guess that maybe you aren't escaping your credentials correctly in the file.  The `\` in the username may be breaking things.  I use a credentials file, I believe it is much safer.

This are the files I use to auto-mount a particular share.

/etc/auto.master

```
/.autofs/cifssrvername /etc/auto.cifssrvername --timeout=600
```

/etc/auto.cifssrvername

```
share   -fstype=cifs,credentials=/etc/samba/.smbauth/smb.authfile.cifssrvername,uid=0,gid=0,file_mode=0664,dir_mode=0775 ://cifssrvername/share
```

I store my credentials in a separate file so I can set better permissions (0400).

/etc/samba/.smbauth/smb.authfile.cifssrvername

```
username=domain\user
password=...
```

The filesystem is then visible in `/.autofs/cifssrvername/share`.

Comment: I am using method 3 of the CentOS wiki at http://www.centos.org/modules/newbb/viewtopic.php?topic_id=12716 , which says that *"/etc/auto.mymount can be made world-unreadable, so, use of the credentials file is not as important."* I have also tried using just the username without DOMAIN\, with the same result, so I don't believe that is the cause. However, I will try your settings soon (and accept the answer if it works.)

Comment: This didn't solve my issues, although it seems that `auto.master` isn't being used (I now believe the **CIFS VFS** errors were from previous failed attempts using `fstab`.) However, I was able to get it working with `/etc/fstab` and a separate credentials file.